# FirebaseStorage.getReferenceFromUrl(Unknown Source)

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-storage

I am getting this error for the last two days and I can't figure out how to solve it, I need to get data(images) stored in firebase as a listview in my Android app I am using RecycleView;

This is the main class:

```
public class MainActivityPersistent extends AppCompatActivity {

    private static final String G_DB_URL = "https://fir-test-ca03d.firebaseio.com/tutorial/list";
    //where the data stored in the firebase
    private boolean isEnabled;

    @Override protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        if(!isEnabled) {
            try {
                FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().setPersistenceEnabled(true);
                isEnabled = true;
            } catch (RuntimeException e) { }
        }

        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        RecyclerView mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.list);
        final ProgressBar mProgressBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar);
        mProgressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        LinearLayoutManager mLinearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager( this );

        mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLinearLayoutManager);
        DatabaseReference ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReferenceFromUrl(G_DB_URL);

        FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<DataModel, ListRowHolder> mAdapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<DataModel, ListRowHolder>(
            DataModel.class,
            R.layout.list_row_item, ListRowHolder.class, ref
        ) {
            @Override protected void populateViewHolder(final ListRowHolder viewHolder,
            DataModel model, int position) {
                mProgressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);

                final StorageReference ref = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReferenceFromUrl(model.image);

                viewHolder.description.setText(model.description);
                Glide.with(MainActivityPersistent.this)
                    .using(new FirebaseImageLoader())
                    .load(ref)
                    .into(viewHolder.image);
            }
        };
    }
}
```

And this is the error I get when I run the app:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                  Process: com.myapplication, PID: 21238
                  java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The storage Uri could not be parsed.
                      at com.google.firebase.storage.FirebaseStorage.getReferenceFromUrl(Unknown Source)
                      at com.myapplication.MainActivityPersistent$1.populateViewHolder(MainActivityPersistent.java:54)
                      at com.myapplication.MainActivityPersistent$1.populateViewHolder(MainActivityPersistent.java:47)
                      at com.firebase.ui.database.FirebaseRecyclerAdapter.onBindViewHolder(FirebaseRecyclerAdapter.java:218)
                      at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Adapter.onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.java:6400)
                      at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Adapter.bindViewHolder(RecyclerView.java:6433)
                      at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.tryBindViewHolderByDeadline(RecyclerView.java:5377)
                      at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.tryGetViewHolderForPositionByDeadline(RecyclerView.java:5640)
                      at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:5482)
                      at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:5478)
                      at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager$LayoutState.next(LinearLayoutManager.java:2215)
                      at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.layoutChunk(LinearLayoutManager.java:1542)
                      at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.fill(LinearLayoutManager.java:1502)
                      at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.onLayoutChildren(LinearLayoutManager.java:595)
                      at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayoutStep2(RecyclerView.java:3625)
                      at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayout(RecyclerView.java:3354)
                      at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.onLayout(RecyclerView.java:3886)
                      at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15631)
                      at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4856)
                      at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:453)
                      at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:388)
                      at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15631)
                      at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4856)
                      at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1677)
                      at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1531)
                      at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1440)
                      at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15631)
                      at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4856)
                      at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:453)
                      at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:388)
                      at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15631)
                      at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4856)
                      at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1677)
                      at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1531)
                      at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1440)
                      at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15631)
                      at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4856)
                      at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:453)
                      at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:388)
                      at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15631)
                      at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4856)
                      at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1677)
                      at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1531)
                      at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1440)
                      at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15631)
                      at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4856)
                      at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:453)
                      at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:388)
                      at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15631)
                      at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4856)
                      at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performLayout(ViewRootImpl.java:2246)
                      at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1968)
                      at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1200)
                      at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:6388)
                      at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:803)
                      at android.view.Choreographer
```

Comment: Got any help. I am also facing same issue

Answer (score 1):

```
FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference(G_DB_URL);
```

Change this from your firebase reference

Comment: Use FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("tutorial/list") or FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("tutorial").child("list"). There is no need to input the full url

Comment: get guide from ** https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/android/create-reference**

Answer (score 0):

Found simply solution just replace:

```
StorageReference storageReference = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReferenceFromUrl(sponsors.getLogoLink());
    Glide.with(mContext)
            .using(new FirebaseImageLoader())
            .load(storageReference)
            .into(sponsorLogo);
```

To simple:

```
Glide.with(mContext)
            .load(sponsors.getLogoLink())
            .into(sponsorLogo);
```

Solved my problem